# how to read all the subdirectories in a given destination which contain Master File in it

Tags: c#

I am having a problem .

My Problem is to read all the subdirectories in a given destination which contain Master file .

I can read subdirectories but i am creating a project which only read given directory which should  contain Master file in the directory .

In the given directory a file called Master file should be there.

I want to write the code like if the given directory doesnot contain any Master file in it it should Jump to another Directory.

My source Directory is @"C:\test.

In @"C:\test" there are many folders and subfolders .

the test directory contains "C:\test\test1\test2\test3 . In this path test3 folder contains Master file test1 and test2 doesn't .

I want to write this code something like this,

```
            MLMReader Reader = new MLMReader();
            Reader.OpenDirectory(@"C:\test");
            if (!File.Exists(test + "\\Master"))
            {
              //i want to loop the "C"\\" and if test1 does not contain 
              // Master File then jump to another directory test2, if 
              //test2 directory contain Master File then the work should
              // continue after finishing go to test3                
            }
```

Is there any way to do .
Any suggestions for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested, but I'm pretty sure the following will work:

```
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "MasterFile", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then you can just `foreach` over the resulting array, if you want to go through all MasterFiles. Or if you just care about the first result, then it's just `paths[0]` -- of course, means it does a lil bit extra work finding all matching paths. And you probably don't need a check for an empty array as an index out of bounds would indicate there's no MasterFile (unless you want to catch that and then rethrow as file not found exception or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

[Linq-to-FileSystem](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqToTree.aspx#filesystem) allows you to perform structured queries on your file system. See the following example:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\test");

// find all subdirectories of test that contains a file / folder called 'Master'
var dirs = dir.Elements()
              .Where(d => d.Elements().Any(i => i.Name == "Master"))
```

Comment: what is the reference i need to add for Elements can u pls say me

Comment: Follow the link above http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqToTree.aspx#filesystem it has the full sourecode and some examples. You need to do a bit of work yourself ;-)

Comment: Cool - by the way, you need to work on your accept / upvotes, you have asked 6 questions but only upvotes one answer. If you don't start accept / upvoting, people will stop answering your questions!

Answer (score 1):

this is my code where I program with directorys, hope it will help you.

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;

 static void Print(string path, int? rec, int? tree, bool color, int? level = 0)
        {
            if ((rec != null && level > rec) || path == null) return; 
            if (rec == null) rec = 0;

            string[] dir;
            string[] fil;

            try
            {
                dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                fil = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }

            foreach (string s in dir)
            {
                WriteSpace(level,tree);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Print(s, rec, tree, color, level + 1);
            }

            if (color)
            {
                ConsoleColor def = Console.ForegroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                foreach (string s in fil) // vypis file
                {
                    WriteSpace(level, tree);
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = def;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string s in fil)
                {
                    WriteSpace(level, tree);
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void WriteSpace(int? level, int? tree)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < level*tree; i++)
                Console.Write(" ");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Recursive Example on how you can traverse a directory structure and look for a certain file, once it is found you can call the corresponding method.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        TraverseDirectory(@"D:\TestDirectory");
    }

    static void DoSomethingWithMaster(string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found master at {0}", path);
    }

    static void TraverseDirectory(string directory)
    {
        var currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

        foreach(var dir in currentDirectory.GetDirectories())
        {
            var currentPath = dir.FullName;

            TraverseDirectory(currentPath);

            var pathToMasterFile = Path.Combine(currentPath, "Master");

            if (File.Exists(pathToMasterFile)) 
               DoSomethingWithMaster(pathToMasterFile);
        }
    }
```

I have the following Folder Structure:

```
D:\TestDirectory\1
D:\TestDirectory\2
D:\TestDirectory\3
D:\TestDirectory\4
D:\TestDirectory\4\Master
D:\TestDirectory\5
```

And when running the above it prints: `Found master at D:\TestDirectory\4`

All you need for this is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

You can also move `TraverseDirectory(currentPath);` to the end of the `foreach`-loop, where you put it depends on when you want to detect the file, do you want to go deep and then climb your way back and check for the Master-file on the way up, or do you want to check for the master file before you enter the next directory?

According to your question, you might want to swap them in my answer and if I understand you correctly, you might not even want to go to the next directory after finding one master-file?

```
foreach(var dir in currentDirectory.GetDirectories())
{
    var currentPath = dir.FullName;


    var pathToMasterFile = Path.Combine(currentPath, "Master");

    if (File.Exists(pathToMasterFile)) 
        DoSomethingWithMaster(pathToMasterFile);

    TraverseDirectory(currentPath);
}
```

In this example, it does exactly what you are saying in your commented code inside your `if`. It will first check TestDirectory\1 for a Master file and then go further down the line. If you don't care about any other Master-files in one sub-directory once it is found, you can just nest `TraverseDirectory(pathToMasterFile)` inside an `else`-block.

**Edit**

You might want to use `EnumerateDirectories`, [see MSDN for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much it works but i have a another problem in my code the dll reads the dat files when Master is find in subdirectories it the code of my line says an error   Reader.ReadMaster();//error is could not find file it is saying like this because it can read subdirectories can u pls help me

Comment: @G Arshiya, you need to change `DoSomethingWithMaster(currentPath);` to:  `DoSomethingWithMaster(Path.Combine(currentPath, "Master"));` I've updated my answer.

Comment: before writing read master i need to write this line Reader.OpenDirectory(test);
                Reader.ReadMaster();  what i should write else than test test is reading only one directory not subdirctory what i should write else than test can u pls say me

Comment: @G Arshiya, I am sorry but I do not understand fully what it is that you are referring to? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: my dll reads only dat files your code finds the master file but when i debug it Reader.ReadMaster;//error - File not found . It means the readMaster could not find the Dat file to write into a text file .when i write Reader.OppenDirectory(test); test does not contain any dat file it only contain subfolders i want to ask you what i should write else then test in Reader.openDirectory(); can u pls say me

Comment: @G Arshiya, Ok, the problem is that you are trying to open a directory, are you sure that the `string` that you are passing to `OpenDirectory` is what you expect it to be? Debug your software, put a breakpoint before that call and inspect the value of `test` and see what it contains.