# List directories that contain a specified file obj c

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

My situation is this. I have a directory /testdir that contains subfolders with various depth. In some of the subfolders there is a file named testfile.txt and some of them do not. what is the easiest way to return in URL form which ones contain this file? I am currently using NSFileManager

Comment: What I am looking for is similar to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198274/how-to-read-all-the-subdirectories-in-a-given-destination-which-contain-master-f) but in obj c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)exproreDirectory:(NSString*)directory
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];

    for (NSString* fileItemName in contents)
    {        
        NSString* fileItemPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileItemName];

        NSDictionary* attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fileItemPath error:&error];

        if ([[attributes fileType] isEqualToString:NSFileTypeDirectory])
        {
            [self exproreDirectory:fileItemPath];
        }
        else if ([[attributes fileType] isEqualToString:NSFileTypeRegular])
        {
            if ([[fileItemPath lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"testfile.txt"])
            {
                // found it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two minor (as in "I'm pedantic" more than "you're wrong") things: NSFileManager's subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath is faster and avoids your code having to be recursive and don't forget to add error checking (if the file manager methods return nil then the returned error tells why).

Comment: @geowar Both methods worked, but used your suggestion of using subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath and removed the recursive code, and it works perfect. Thanks guys!